# CSS about pure css collapsible menu

Tags: html, css, menu, collapsable

I wonder is there any good example of pure css only collapsible menu

This is an example of it

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-tree-menu

The example uses `input:checked` as the trigger to change children from `display:none` to `display:block`

This is example use `li:hover` to do that

[Make pure css collapsible menu triggered by down arrow for mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014077/make-pure-css-collapsible-menu-triggered-by-down-arrow-for-mobile-browsers)

But I want to use `li:click` as the trigger, is this possible?

Thank you very much for your advice, and very appreciate that I can have a example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do this purely with CSS, :click isn't even a valid css selector attribute(someone please correct me if I'm wrong here). You can only use: active, hover & visited. You CAN however use javascript or jQuery

eg. `$('li').click(function(){//Do Something});`

Comment: Down-voter, please comment why so we can improve the answer for future users and not simply troll SO.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes we can!**

You can use the `:focus` pseudo which is activaded on click: http://jsfiddle.net/w5zev/2/ deactivation is more tricky for this technique.

Taken from a google search which led me here: http://quhno.internetstrahlen.de/myopera/csstests/collapsible-paragraph.html#url